# Hornetq fails to create a connection

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x, netty, hornetq

I am using Hornetq server for JMS communication. Connection is established many-a -times but at certain instances I am not able to create a connection which gives the message "Failed to create session factory" or an Interrupted exception
Stack trace would be as follows,

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
      [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:587)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:119)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:114)
      [java]     at com.aircell.abs.acpu.framework.AcpuGenericQueue.<init>(AcpuGenericQueue.java:79)
      [java]     at com.aircell.abs.acpu.framework.AcpuSendQueue.<init>(AcpuSendQueue.java:58)
      [java]     at com.aircell.abs.acpu.framework.AcpuSendQueue.replyMessage(AcpuSendQueue.java:100)
      [java]     at com.aircell.abs.acpu.networkcontrol.NetworkControlServiceImpl$QueueHandler.handleMessage(NetworkControlServiceImpl.java:167)
      [java]     ... 9 more
      [java] Caused by: org.hornetq.api.core.HornetQInterruptedException: java.lang.InterruptedException
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnection.write(NettyConnection.java:244)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.send(ChannelImpl.java:267)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.send(ChannelImpl.java:194)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$PingRunnable.send(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1765)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1369)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1069)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:246)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:828)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:583)
      [java]     ... 15 more
      [java] Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
      [java]     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1301)
      [java]     at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
      [java]     at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnection.write(NettyConnection.java:175)
      [java]     ... 23 more
```

Comment: Can we see you client configuration file

Comment: Only default configurations are used..

Comment: configuration or code its difficult to understand the problem.